# TestUnit outdated with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, testunit

I read that TestUnit was replaced in Ruby 1.9.3 itself with Minitest and that Rails 4 is using MiniTest.

Should I move all my TestUnit Tests to MiniTest or is this not necessary?

Comment: No answer? :/ Cant imagein..

Comment: By the way, I don't know if my question is relevant to yours, but I have am asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843523/is-it-still-possible-to-use-test-unit-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is active and busy then, yes minitest is a more widely used and supported framework than TestUnit and it may be valuable to make the change depending on your needs.